# Find where not exists, based on value from third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called `Cities` which is like the following:

```
+--------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+
| CityID |    City     | State | TimeZone | UserAccess |
+--------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+
|      1 | Albany      | NY    |        4 |          1 |
|      2 | Allentown   | PA    |        6 |          1 |
|      3 | Albuquerque | NM    |        4 |          1 |
|      4 | Amarillo    | TX    |        3 |          1 |
|      5 | Atlanta     | GA    |        4 |          1 |
+--------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+
```

I have another table called `CitiesToRegions` like the following:

```
+--------+----------+
| CityID | RegionID |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |       14 |
|      1 |       15 |
|      2 |       14 |
|      3 |       11 |
|      4 |       12 |
|      4 |       13 |
|      5 |       12 |
|      5 |       13 |
+--------+----------+
```

I have a `Regions` table like the following:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| RegionID |  Region   | TypeID |
+----------+-----------+--------+
|       10 | West      |      1 |
|       11 | West      |      2 |
|       12 | South     |      1 |
|       13 | South     |      2 |
|       14 | Northeast |      1 |
|       15 | Northeast |      2 |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

What I'm trying to do is write a query so that I can see where I am missing a `CitiesToRegions` designation based upon the `TypeID` of the `Regions` table. Here is what I have so far which is returning nothing, which I'm sure is because my first join finds no nulls due to the `CityID` having a `RegionID` assigned to it. I just can't figure out how to actually write what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cities.CityID
FROM Cities
    INNER JOIN CitiesToRegions on Cities.CityID = CitiesToRegions.CityID
    FULL JOIN Regions on CitiesToRegions.RegionID = Regions.RegionID
WHERE (CitiesToRegions.RegionID is null) AND (Cities.UserAccess=1) AND (Regions.TypeID != 1)
```

What I am wanting to see for query results is the following since it is the only `CityID` that does not have a `RegionID` of `Regions.TypeID = 1`.

```
+--------+
| CityID |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
```

NOTE: I'm not concerned with seeing the ones missing `TypeID` of 2 as I would run the same query and pass in the `TypeID` as a variable:

Comment: CitiesToRegions.RegionID will never be null with that data and those joins. An inner join between Cities and CitiesToRegions means all those will match and the full join to Regions is kind of pointless because you then match on a Cities value anyway. I would probably go with a `NOT EXISTS` clause rather than joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you need - I find a `not exists` sub-query is clearer to get the logic right then a complex join.

```
select *
from Cities C
where not exists (
  select 1
  from CitiesToRegions CR
  inner join Regions R on CR.RegionID = R.RegionID and R.TypeID = 1
  where CR.CityID = C.CityID
)
```